# Error "vssphost4.exe has stopped working" when openning SharePoint project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a machine with VS 2013 and 2010 installed side by side and When i open a SharePoint 2010 project with Vs2013 which have Visual Webpart(.ascx file) or when i go to Properties Tab of my Project i get the following error:

> vssphost4.exe has stopped working

Also i lost Intellisense in .aspx or .ascx files on "asp" tags but not "SharePoint" tags!!.
At the beginning VS was fine until i installed SharePoint language pack and this errors showed up.
As far as i know VS2013 use this file(vssphost4.exe) to communicate with SharePoint. also when trying to add SharePoint Connection via Server Explorer i get this error:

> A task was canceled

I must mention that i can't Deploy or Retract the project either(error in Recycling App pool or deploy step).
This is waht i got from Event Viewer:

> Faulting application name: vssphost4.exe, version: 12.0.21005.1, timestamp: 0x524fa958
>
> Faulting module name: mscorwks.dll, version:2.0.50727.5448, time stamp: 0x4e153960
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
>
> Fault offset: 0x00000000004ad824
>
> Faulting process id: 0x%9
>
> Faulting application start time: 0x%10
>
> Faulting application path: %11 Faulting
>
> module path: %12 Report Id: %13

And before that record i got this:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5448 - Fatal Execution Engine Error
> (000007FEF2EF7836) (80131506)

I reinstalled VS2013 but no chance.

Comment: You are correct about vssphost4 communicating between VS and SP. One thing I've noticed with VS2012 (assuming this applies to VS2013 as well) is that when developing user controls and pages, VS connects to SP when you open the markup file in the editor. I'm not sure what it's doing when it does that, but it does. Which language pack was it that you installed?

Comment: Also, are there any entries in the event logs?

Comment: I installed Persian language pack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to conclusion which is all about Persian Language Pack and its Persian Calendar specifically. and by uninstalling Persian Calendar the problem resolved.

But there is times that you will face this problem.
For instance when you have opened multiple instance of VS and its debugging location is same as the currently running visual studio debugging location. the Solution is close all opened visual studio and reopen your project.